# Postfix - relaying specific email addresses within a mydestination domain

Tags: email, postfix-mta, relay

Having some issues trying to get something working on postfix.

That is, I have a domain `abc.com` which is a destination domain on my postfix server `1.2.3.4`, it hosts mailboxes for addresses in this domain locally by default - straight-forward.

However, I would like to be able to "relay" specific email addresses from within this same domain (say: `userx@abc.com`) to another postfix server `[5.6.7.8]:2525` - yet still retaining the original ability of being able to deliver mail to all other addresses `*@abc.com` locally on my original postfix server `1.2.3.4`.

Is anyone able to advise how I can go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Update 1:

...still have one issue.

So I have `transport` file:

```
userx@abc.com  relay:[5.6.7.8]:2525
*@abc.com  local
```

And `main.cf`:

```
relay_domains = abc.com
```

This config sends to the relay perfect as I want, but any other addresses (in the wildcard scope) do not get delivered as they try to go straight back out the default relay server (another server altogether), where-as instead I'd like them to hit `/etc/aliases` or a local mailbox.

Comment: This is still and issue, anyone able to help at all?